# how to see background color of div when if move on image

Tags: html, css, background-color

My Code: [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/5fyjxt2L/2/)

HTML:

```
<div class="d1">
    <img src="http://i57.tinypic.com/30cw0ut_th.png">
    <div class="d2">
        Pic 1
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.d1{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% center;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    visibility: visible;
}
img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;   
}
.d2{
    margin-top: -50px;
    margin left: 20px;
    background-color: green;
    color: blue;
}
```

I have an image and I want to try Move a div on Image. My Div [with class d2] has moved on image, but I can't see background color of it. how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give the second div `position:relative` to ensure the correct stacking order.

```css
.d1{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% center;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    visibility: visible;
    */
}
img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;   
}
.d2{
    margin-top: -50px;
    margin left: 20px;
    background-color: green;
    color: blue;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">
    <img src="http://i57.tinypic.com/30cw0ut_th.png"/>
    <div class="d2">
        Pic 1
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to add `Position:relative` on `.d2`

```css
.d1{
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 border: 1px solid #000;
 overflow: hidden;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 50% center;
 background-size: 100% auto;
 visibility: visible;
   
}
img{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%; 
}
.d2{
        margin-top: -50px;
        margin left: 20px;
 background-color: green;
 color: blue;
        position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">
 <img src="http://i57.tinypic.com/30cw0ut_th.png">
    <div class="d2">
     Pic 1
    </div>
</div>
```

also see the Link below
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_position_relative